# UnsatisfiedLinkError after changing Eclipse workspace

Tags: java, eclipse, lwjgl, slick2d, unsatisfiedlinkerror

I've been using the lwjgl and Slick2D libraries in something I'm working on. At some point I needed to split up my Minecraft Bukkit plugins from my other java programs, so I moved the java programs to another workspace. After doing this however, my project with the aformentioned libraries fail to work, giving the error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no lwjgl in java.library.path

The stack trace points to where I initialize my AppGameContainer in the main() block:

```
AppGameContainer appgc;
    try{
        appgc = new AppGameContainer(new Game(gamename)); // <-- This line
        appgc.setDisplayMode(800, 600, false);
        appgc.setTargetFrameRate(FPS);
        appgc.start();
    }catch(SlickException ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

This program compiled and ran perfectly fine before the workspace migration, and NOTHING has changed except the workspace location. I've removed and re-added the library jars (via Add JAR, not Add External JAR, the jar files are in /lib/jars/, as they were before, relative to the project). I've even attempted to re-add them as external jars, but still no luck. The compiler isn't reporting any errors prior to attempting to run the program.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the Deployment Assembly category for project options (assuming you're using a project type that has that category)?
It's possible you updated the compile-time reference, but not the runtime reference.

Comment: Not sure how to check/set project types in Eclipse O.o Wasn't even aware there were seperate references for compile/run.

Answer (score 0):

When you moved the java programs, you probably didn't move the files that tell your development program where the natives are.

```
appgc = new AppGameContainer(new Game(gamename)); //<-- This line
```

The UnsatisfiedLinkError was most likely thrown because LWJGL/Slick didn't have the natives required to initialize AppGameContainer. Try linking the natives.

[Linking natives in Eclipse](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0v56I5UWrYY)

[Linking natives in Netbeans](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4IUAQEnYtK8)